# Borsuk theorem and Open map throrem

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega\subset X$ be open, $X$ is a real linear normed space. Assume also that $f=I-F: \Omega\to X$ is a completely continuous field and locally one-to-one where $I$ is the identity map and $F$ is a completely map. Prove $f$ is an open map.

I guess the Homotopy invariance should be used.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please provide some additional explanation of the notation, and give us your attempt thus far. Questions without the asker's work are not generally received well here.

Comment: In particular, what does it mean for $F$ to be a complete(ly) map?